# Parse.com PFQueyTableviewController does not load more than 12 entires on iphone 6

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I tried everything, but for some reason on iphone 6, whenever I show a uitableview with data from parse, after the row 12, it keeps missing entries and I have to pull to refresh or keep going up and down to load the entries in the view.
Any idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hi cldev, the docs for this class (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/paginationEnabled) reveal 2 variables that may be of interest to you; objectsPerPage and paginationEnabled. As a first port of call I would set paginationEnabled to NO and objectsPerPage to something greater than 12.

Comment: I did use these variables. I think the problem is scrolling down the uitableview. It shows all the entires up to 12 because it is limit the screen size of the iphone.

Comment: I think you should post some of the relevant code.

Comment: The code is in every parse example. There is not a single thing different from it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue after doing some research.
 -> Disable Use Size Classes